# Custom filter is stuck on

Tags: support

I had a custom filter for questions in tag [co.combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics) with no answer. It seems to be "stuck" in the sense that if I go to the "generic" page for that tag, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics, the window title is "*Custom filtered 'co.combinatorics' questions*" and only questions with no (upvoted) answer are shown.

Moreover, if I go to any other tag page (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/integer-sequences) the window title says "Custom filtered ..." and only questions with no (upvoted) answer are shown.

I say "had" rather than "have" in the first sentence because I tried deleting the custom filter, and that doesn't fix the problem. It seems that the only way I can view an unfiltered tag list is to open a separate browser or an incognito window and load the page without logging in.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you try clicking on the orange "Filter" button and changing the options? You will probably see the box "No answers" checked in the first column, and the radio button for "Newest" selected in the second column. If so, can you try unchecking the box for "No answers", and then clicking on "Apply filter", and then renavigating to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics to see if that helps?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, that works, thanks.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5698/custom-filter-is-stuck-on#comment28793_5698), maybe you can post that as an answer so that this question isn't marked unanswered?

Comment: @LSpice sure, I'll try and do that in some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that any filter options selected under the columns "Filter by" and "Sorted by" are sticky. For instance, if you decided to filter by "No answers" and sort by "Newest", and then you clicked on "Apply filter", then these settings are remembered when you perform *any* tag search.

To remove the custom filtering, you can click on the "Filter" button, select your preferred filter and sort options, and then click on "Apply filter". **Note that the settings are remembered only when you've clicked on "Apply filter".**

In particular, if you wish to use custom filters, then, after you've saved your custom filter, just remember to change the filter options to your preferred default settings and click on "Apply filter". (It might be worth mentioning that you can click on "Save custom filter" without clicking on "Apply filter". This might save some trouble.)

---

I believe that the filter and sort options are sticky by design. There is a feature request to [add a "Reset filter" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331365), which was posted under the announcement on Meta SE about the release of custom filters, but I doubt that it has the attention of SE staff.